# Create a form that adds new rows to a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

In Rails 4, how can I make a form that creates new rows in a join table, in a has_many, through association? Specifically, what do I pass into my check_box() input?

Example:
Students enroll in many Courses. This is a has_many to has_many association. My join table is "student_course_assignments".

Models:

```
Student
has_many :student_course_assignments
has_many :courses, through: :student_course_assignments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_course_assignments

Course
has_many :student_course_assignments
has_many :students, through: :student_course_assignments

StudentCourseAssignment
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :course
```

Controller Students

```
def show
  @student.student_course_assignments.build
end
```

View at `myapp.com/student/1`

```
# This form lets you add new rows to student_course_assignments, for the given student.
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :student_course_assignments do |join_fields| %>
    <% Courses.all.each do |course| %>
      <%= join_fields.checkbox(course.id) %>  # What should be passed in here??
      <span><%= course.name %></span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any advice on how to structure the form that shows checkboxes for every course, and lets me check a course that should be added to the student_course_assignemnts db would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sigh, those questions have been asked so many times... http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=HABTM rails really has to make this easier and more clear!

Comment: that's for Rails 3 in 2011 - 

the point of this question is to figure out the most efficient way to construct this using Rails 4.

Comment: i think nothing has changed in that regard...

Comment: Blah, that's unfortunate. Let me dig for a bit and see if I can find a cleaner solution than the one I've seen in the railscasts and around SO for Rails 3. If not, I'll close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ActiveRecord**

You'll probably be looking for the [`<<` ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) feature:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :students do
    #could be a member route
    match :add, via: [:get, :post]
end

#app/controller/students_controller.rb
def add
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    if request.post?
        @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
        @student.student_course_assignments << @course
    end
end

#app/views/students/add.html.erb
<%= form_for @student, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :course_id %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Yours**

For your code, I'd do this:

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
    <% Courses.all.each do |course| %>
      <%= f.checkbox :student_course_assignment_ids, course.id %>
      <span><%= course.name %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will populate the collection of :student_course_assignments for you I think. You shouldn't have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if you're not creating new `course` objects